# Why updating an entity changes the fields of its child to null?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities with `ManyToOne` relationship ( Product and Owner). The problem is that when I try to update the Product entity those fields of it that are not included in the form and the fields of  it's owner's entity will be changed to null.

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Prodcut implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Owner owner;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    ....

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner")
    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Owner implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    ....
}
```

In this case after update as code is not included in the form will be changed to null, and all fields of owner also will be changed to null.

**Update Form**

```
<s:form method="POST" autocomplete="on" action="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="product.id" value="${product.id}"/>
                <s:select name="product.owner.id"
                          id="product.owner.id"
                          label="Owner"
                          list="listOfOwners"
                          headerKey=""
                          headerValue="Owner"
                          value="%{product.owner.id}"
                          />
               <input type="text" name="product.name" value="${product.name}"/>
               ....
```

**Hibernate code**

```
 final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            try {

                Product product1 = (Product) session.get(Product.class,product.getId());
                Owner owner1 = (Owner) session.get(Owner.class, product.getOwner().getId());
                product.setOwner(owner1);
                product.setCode(product1.getCode);

                if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
                      tx.commit();
                }

                return pro;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried to retrieve the product object from database and replace the values of those fields that are not provided in the form but it runs into an error "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last strategy is the good one. You msut simply not call `update()` or any other method:

```
Product persistentProduct = (Product) session.get(Product.class, product.getId());
persistentProduct.setName(product.getName());
// copy other fields
// nothing more
```

Comment: thanks it works, but is not there any other method to achieve the same results? 30 fields of product class are included in the form, if I want to add them all I need to write 30 separate lines as you did for setName. Also may I know when I should use session.update?

Comment: You could probably a prepopulated Product as your struts form bean instead of using an empty product, but I don't know struts well enough to say. But anyway, If you have 30 (gasp!) fields in a single form, having to copy 30 fields is normal. Long forms imply long code. This is trivial code though.

Comment: Actually the form is used to edit the product and I am sending a prepopulated object to the form to show the values as its default values.

Comment: What I mean is that, when you submit the form, it should not populate an empty Product, but the existing Product having the same ID. This is something doable with Spring, but I don't know if it is with Struts.

Comment: Uou should use update when you want to replace an existing, persistent object, not already loaded into the session, by another, detached object, containing the complete new state. In general, I avoid it like the plague. merge is a safer alternative (but which wouldn't solve your problem).

Comment: I've posted that as a question but someone vote it down, would you please vote it up thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185147/how-to-submit-values-of-a-form-to-a-prepopulated-object